# Add directory to path for all shells and users in SLES 11.1

Tags: shell, path, suse

I'm using a server running Suse Enterprise 11.1. I need to add some locations to the path for all users and for all the shells. Is there a nice and easy way to do this or do I have to modify the profile file for each shell.

Also I don't know if this is the default config for suse or if someone mess the server up, but there isn't a /etc/profile nor a /etc/shellnameprofile.local

How can I archive this? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add to `/etc/profile.local` and the `PATH` addition will survive upgrades for the regular users. For root check the `.profile` of root to see if you set the path hard-coded there.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the default path for all users in [`/etc/login.defs`](http://man.sourcentral.org/SUSE122/5+login.defs).

```
ENV_SUPATH PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/extra/dir
ENV_PATH PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/extra/dir
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Just in addition - If a SuSE dist and the bash shell is used, you can put the path modifications also into

***/etc/bash.bashrc.local***

```
PATH=$PATH:/my/myscripts
export PATH
```

Comment: But if I need it to work in other shells like ksh it doesnt't work.

Comment: Yes, it's just an additional information for other SLES / bash users